# Stereo Compilation Software with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, software-recommendations, stereo-imagery, arcgis-stereo-analyst

Does anyone know of stereo compilation software that will allow for the writing into a PostGIS database?

Both Datum and Stereo Analyst will write to an ESRI Geodatabase.  Standard stereo compilation software will write to a DGN, but I am unaware of anything that will write directly into a PostGIS database.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would have to digitize in a GIS rather than the stereo plotting software to write directly to a PostGIS database (or any other database). Stereo Analyst (for ArcGIS) allows to use all the formats available in ArcGIS by complete integration to ArcMap's window. There's also PurView that integrate very well. I'm not sure for Summit Evolution, I think it's not so easy to use ArcGIS tools for digitization. I'm unaware of other open source alternatives such as 3D digitization in OpenJump, QGIS or GRASS that usually better integrate PostGIS.